# Impossible to access an url in Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

Just below my issue:
I installed Android Studio in offline mode.
I created a new simulated device in Android Studio.
My PC is connected to an internal wired network with no internet connection but with a intranet connection filtered by a proxy.
From my emulator, I tried to access to an url that should be accessible without using proxy but it does not work. I do not understand why. Can you help me ?

My second question is:
Is it possible to connect an Android emulator to a wired network with a proxy ?
I did not find any documentation or existing questions about this topic.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the solution by setting properly proxy parameters into emulator wifi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).